# Validator for comboBox and phn no

Tags: codenameone

```
ComboBox companyCity = new ComboBox();
companyCity.setUIID("TextField");
companyCity.addItem("Choose City");
for (Map<String, Object> entry : alacc.responseCity) {
    String cityName = (String) entry.get("name");
    companyCity.addItem(cityName);
}

TextField companyPhone = new TextField();
companyPhone.setHint("Phone");
```

1)For combobox, using addConstraint(companyCity, new LengthConstraint(2)) doesnt work since it has "choose city" text already. Do we have any other constraint particularly for comboBox?

2)Also i have to validate phone no. I have used addConstraint(companyPhone, new RegexConstraint(phoneRegex, "Must be valid phone number")); But what is phoneRegex here?
Do i have to use my own regular expression for it? eg      final String phoneRegex = "^((\d{3}-|\(\d{3}\)\s?)?\d{3}-|^\d{3}(\.)?\d{3}\3)\d{4}$";
If so, Why is it not define as default as of url regex, email regex etc?

3)when i use "addConstraint(companyPhone, new RegexConstraint(phoneRegex, "Must be valid phone number"));" the error msg ie. "must be valid phone number" doesnt appear in the 
textfield.How to display the error msg?

Answer (score 1):

1. No. You will need to create a constraint for combo box selection.
2. Phone's are a bit more complex to properly validate than even email. We didn't have a decent regex version of that.
3. Use `setShowErrorMessageForFocusedComponent(true)`

Comment: thankyou shai... But for combobox i cannot do new LengthConstraint(2) since i already have "choose city". Can you give me some idea on combobox? I have one more issue, the button is disabled until all the req. fields are filled. It creates a bit confusion.So what i want is to set the text of submit button as "all fields are compulsary" and when all the fields are filled up & when the button is clickable, how can i change the button text into submit? Can i do that.

Comment: `Constraint` is a really simple interface with 2 methods. Just override the isValid method and check the combo.